# Why are constructor parameters made into members for case classes?

Tags: scala

```
  {
      class MyClass(name: String) {} 
      val x = new MyClass("x")
      println(x.name)         // Error name is not a member of MyClass
  }
```

but

```
  {
      abstract class Base

      case class MyClass(name: String) extends Base {}

      var x = new MyClass("x")
      println(x.name)           // name is a member of MyClass
  }
```

So, what's the deal with case classes? Why are all of the constructor parameters turned into variables.

Comment: Whenever I execute the above code I get the expected "x" as output. Which version are you using? And which environment?

Comment: By the way, case classes not only make public members from constructors, but they also do allow you to instantiate objects by means of out-of-the-box provided factory methods (`apply()` in companion object), i.e. you could do `var x = MyClass("x")` in your case (`new` omitted). And, therefore, as it have been  already mentioned in answers, by pattern matching `x` against that `MyClass(arg)` you get an ability to decompose your data structures intuitively via deconstructors in the same companion object. ( `List`s, `Map`a and others are good example of usability of the approach.)

Comment: Your comment regarding the output of `println(x.name)` in the second example is wrong. `x.name` _is_ defined for `case class MyClass`.

Comment: @Jens. The first version fails for me in Scala 2.10 (compiling within Eclipse with Scala IDE).  "value name is not a member of MyClass"

Answer (score 2):

`name` is member in both examples, but private in your first example while public in your second. Case classes make their constructor parameters `public val` by default.

Answer (score 2):

Just to be clear, the constructor arguments aren't used to create variables, they're used to create values.

If you specify `val` in your first example, the non-case class:

```
class MyClass(val name: String) {}
```

then you also get the argument translated into a public value, the same as is done for the case class.

In the example on the [Scala-Lang site](http://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/107) it says:

> It makes only sense to define case classes if pattern matching is used
>   to decompose data structures. The following object defines a pretty
>   printer function for our lambda calculus representation:

followed by the example code:

```
object TermTest extends Application {   def printTerm(term: Term) {
    term match {
      case Var(n) =>
        print(n)
      case Fun(x, b) =>
        print("^" + x + ".")
        printTerm(b)
      case App(f, v) =>
        Console.print("(")
        printTerm(f)
        print(" ")
        printTerm(v)
        print(")")
    }   }   def isIdentityFun(term: Term): Boolean = term match {
    case Fun(x, Var(y)) if x == y => true
    case _ => false   }   val id = Fun("x", Var("x"))   val t = Fun("x", Fun("y", App(Var("x"), Var("y"))))   printTerm(t)   println   println(isIdentityFun(id))   println(isIdentityFun(t)) }
```

Comment: "they don't have any state or functionality" - Not true. `case class Foo(a: String, var b: String = "") { def apply(): String = a+b }`

Answer (score 2):

Pattern matching is the most important but not the only application for case classes. Another important point is that they implement the `equals` and `hashCode` methods in terms of the constructor arguments (aka product elements). Therefore, case classes are very useful for defining data structures that serve as elements in sets or keys in maps. That in turn only makes sense if these elements are visible.

Compare:

```
class Foo(val i: Int)

val set1 = Set(new Foo(33))
set1.contains(new Foo(33))  // false!!
```

And:

```
case class Bar(val i: Int)

val set2 = Set(Bar(33)
set2.contains(Bar(33))      // true!
```

Two case class instances with equal parameters are equal themselves. You can imagine them representing some "constants". This implies that you should not have mutable state in them.

You can, however, use a second parameter list to exclude arguments from the equality:

```
case class Baz(i: Int)(val n: Long)

Baz(33)(5L) == Baz(33)(6L)  // true!
```

---

Another useful feature which implies that the constructor arguments become values, is making copies. This is the way immutable data is changes—you create a new instance with a particular value changed, leaving the original value in place.

```
case class Person(name: String, age: Int)

val p1 = Person("Fuzzi", 33)
val p2 = p1.copy(age = 34)
```

The copy method uses default values for all unspecified argument, taking those values from the constructor args.

Answer (score 1):

To add something to my comment due to lack of available space: consider the following example case class:

`case class My(x: Int)`

If you save it to file and pass it to `scalac -print`, you get following expanded code (I removed unimportant stuff):

```
case class My extends Object with Product with Serializable {
<caseaccessor> <paramaccessor> private[this] val x: Int = _; 
<stable> <caseaccessor> <accessor> <paramaccessor> def x(): Int = My.this.x;
```

Notice `<caseaccessor>`s here.

And then companion object:

```
      <synthetic> object My extends runtime.AbstractFunction1 with Serializable {
        case <synthetic> def apply(x: Int): My = new My(x);
        case <synthetic> def unapply(x$0: My): Option = if (x$0.==(null))
          scala.this.None
        else
          new Some(scala.Int.box(x$0.x()));
        case <synthetic> <bridge> def apply(v1: Object): Object = My.this.apply(scala.Int.unbox(v1));
//...
```

Notice `apply` and `unapply` here. If you look at complete output yourself, you'll learn more about how scala generates your code.