# Are constructor parameters treated differently in classes vs. case classes?

Tags: scala, case-class, scala-3

In the book, "Programming in Scala 5th Edition", it is mentioned in the fourth chapter that we can create class' objects using the following way if a class is a case class:

```
scala> case class Person(name: String, age: Int)
// defined case class Person

scala> val p = Person("Sally", 39)
val p: Person = Person(Sally,39)
```

I do not find it different from the following *normal* way:

```
scala> class Person(name: String, age: Int)
// defined class Person

scala> val p = Person("Aviral", 24)
val p: Person = Person@7f5fcfe9
```

I tried accessing the objects in both the cases and there was a difference. When I declare the same class as a `case` class, I can access its members: `p.name`, `p.age` whereas if I try to do the same with a *normally* declared class, I get the following error:

```
1 |p.name
  |^^^^^^
  |value name cannot be accessed as a member of (p : Person) from module class rs$line$3$.
```

How are the two cases different as far as constructing an object is considered?

Comment: Have you reviewed the answers found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2312881/4993128)?

Comment: @jwvh I was considering clicking on your link and closing this as duplicate. However, I found only a horrendously long wall of someone's vaguely related overly broad answers from 2010, 2013, 2017, and I don't know when else. I don't think that it's helpful to suggest to newcomers asking about Scala-3 to read everything that has been written since 2010.

Comment: This [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61722892/are-case-class-constructor-parameters-public-val-fields-by-default) is also not a good duplicate, because it has a different focus.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18194005/why-are-constructor-parameters-made-into-members-for-case-classes or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24113964/whats-the-difference-between-class-and-case-class-in-stream-in-scala

Comment: @MarioGalic Looks good. If Aviral agrees that this answers the question, I'd propose to close it as duplicate.

Comment: I'm not sure this should be tagged [tag:scala-3], since it's not specific to Scala 3.

Answer (score 2):

As the [Tour Of Scala](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/case-classes.html) or the [Scala 3 book](https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/book/taste-modeling.html#case-classes) says

> When you create a case class with parameters, the parameters are public `val`s.

Therefore, in

```
case class Person(name: String, age: Int)
```

both `name` and `age` will be public, unlike in an ordinary class.